# Receiving and broad casting messages from mobile phones with PHP

Tags: php

There is a web site 
http://www.pringit.com
i want to receive text messages from mobile phones using php, like this web site.

the user makes his account at this web site and registers his mobile fone number there then if admin or any other person who has made groups there (at the web site) he can send a message from his mobile to the web site server then from that server the message is broad casted or multi casted or uni casted according to the sender's wish, my question is that i want to do a work like this, now i want some guidance, about this, i want to know that is that task is done by using some sort of api like tropo or urbanairship etc?, if that is then i will go for api, or there is another way to do this, plz. guide me how to do this, or how to go about this thanx an Regards  Saad

Comment: do you have code? or anything you have started?

Comment: You must use sms gateway ,please search for a good provider in your area

Comment: No Joseph this is still an idea, didn't start working till now, i just wanted some guidance so than i can start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use any service providers API to send sms. You can search for the best service provider in your area.

If you purchase some credits ,most of the case they will have give the integration guide or code

You can select XML or json API for this . You will have to do the rest of code likek user authentication,grouping etc

http://www.twilio.com/ is one of them

Comment: Thanx duke i used tropo api to send messages to the user's mobile phone, here i want to is that i want to receive text messages from user who will obviously a subscriber of the web site and then brod cast, multi cast or uni cast that text message, now i found an api, here is its url, http://www.txtimpact.com/api.asp , do u think it can fulfill my requirement or there is another way?

Comment: You can check the facilities with their customer support ,that would be bettter